# ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms with no synonyms

Tags: sql, plsql

I have been using a script run from a batch file to create and edit a table.  As far as I cold tell it was working and I worked on a different issue.

However, at some point something has gone wrong.

In PLSQL Developer I tried to select from the table and I got the error:

```
ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
```

If I try to drop the table I get the error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I have never, intentionally, created and synonyms so I checked with this:

```
SELECT owner,synonym_name,table_owner,table_name from dba_synonyms where synonym_name='broken_table';
```

There are no results returned.  The other similar questions on here do not seem to have the same situation or the actual solution, can anyone give any advice on how to proceed here?
(as you can guess sql is not my strong suit).

Comment: Try `where synonym_name='BROKEN_TABLE'` in capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

I got the ORA-01775 error from trying to access a table via a synonym where the table did not exist.  The table had been dropped and had not yet been recreated.  The synonym was still there.  There was no looping synonym.